# Favorite editor field in careers is too short

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign, jobs

I want to have more room for entering my favorite editor in Careers. IMHO it really depends on the environment and my task.

If I'm developing an Android application I prefer Eclipse (maybe in the near future Android Studio).
If I'm developing a desktop application I prefer Visual Studio.
If I'm developing a bash script I prefer vim.
If I'm developing a website with PHP I prefer Dreamwaver and for ASP, Visual Studio.
If I'm developing a Windows script I prefer Notepad++.

How should I put all that information in such a small field?

Comment: vim only has three letters, so what's the problem?

Comment: I would never try to programm a Android app with vim. So I use multiple editors, I just wanted to point out why I use an editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply list the editors you use in that field (even though it says to specify an *editor* and not multiple *editors*), and expand on them in the Background section that follows, describing which editors you use for what purposes. In fact, the help text for that section tells you just that in its last paragraph:

> Feel free to elaborate on your first computer, and your favorite editor. What makes you an individual? What are your turn-ons? What are your turn-offs? What do you do in your spare time? Spin us a yarn!

Again, it says "favorite *editor*", but there are no hard and fast rules to this. It's entirely free form.